# Get multiple key/value pairs from jsonb (pg 12)

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

Postgres 12

```
table_1:
  id int,
  attributes jsonb,
  layer_id int -- foreign key
table_2:
  id int,
  labels jsonb, -- this is an array, and its elements correspond to some of the keys in table_1.attributes
  layer_id int -- foreign key
```

After joining these tables on `layer_id = layer_id`, I want to only select the key/value pairs from table_1.attributes that match the keys in table_2.labels

e.g, if we have table_1 row like:

```
attributes: { "a": 1, "b": 3, "c": "hello" },
layer_id: 5
```

and table_2 row like:

```
labels: '["a", "c"]',
layer_id: 5
```

my objective would be to get a column containing `{ "a": 1, "c": "hello" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

by the following method we can get the desired object w/o getting a row for each label (this can be prohibitive when dealing w/ millions of rows)

1. Get array of desired labels
2. Remove these keys from the attributes object
3. Get the remaining keys
4. Remove those from the original attributes object, leaving behind the key/values corresponding to the desired labels e.g.,

```
with table_1 (layer_id, attributes) as (
  values (5, '{"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": "hello"}'::jsonb),
         (7, '{"d": 0, "e": 9, "f": "bye"}'::jsonb)
), table_2 (layer_id, labels) as (
  values (5, '["a", "c"]'::jsonb),
         (7, '[]'::jsonb)
)
  select t1.layer_id,
         a.attributes result
    from table_1 t1
         join table_2 t2 on t2.layer_id = t1.layer_id
         cross join lateral (
             SELECT t1.attributes - ARRAY (
                    SELECT 
                        jsonb_object_keys(attributes - ARRAY (
                            SELECT
                                jsonb_array_elements_text(labels)))) AS attributes) a
   group by t1.layer_id, a.attributes

 layer_id |         result
----------+------------------------
        5 | {"a": 1, "c": "hello"}
        7 | []
(2 rows)
```

**ORIGINAL SOLUTION**

Expand using `jsonb_array_elements()`, and then aggregate with `jsonb_object_agg()`:

```
with table_1 as (
  select 5 as layer_id, '{"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": "hello"}'::jsonb as attributes
), table_2 as (
  select 5 as layer_id, '["a", "c"]'::jsonb as labels
)
select t2.layer_id, jsonb_object_agg(l.label, t1.attributes->l.label) 
  from table_2 t2 
       cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(t2.labels) as l(label)
       join table_1 t1 on t1.layer_id = t2.layer_id
 group by t2.layer_id;

 layer_id |    jsonb_object_agg    
----------+------------------------
        5 | {"a": 1, "c": "hello"}
(1 row)
```

To deal with empty `labels` elements, try the below.  I was not able to figure out how to get this to work without making the original query into a CTE since `jsonb_object_agg()` will not accept `null` for a label.

```
with table_1 (layer_id, attributes) as (
  values (5, '{"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": "hello"}'::jsonb),
         (7, '{"d": 0, "e": 9, "f": "bye"}'::jsonb)
), table_2 (layer_id, labels) as (
  values (5, '["a", "c"]'::jsonb),
         (7, '[]'::jsonb)
), expand as (
  select t1.layer_id,
         jsonb_object_agg(l.label, t1.attributes->l.label) result
    from table_1 t1
         join table_2 t2 on t2.layer_id = t1.layer_id
         cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(t2.labels) as l(label)
   group by t1.layer_id
)
select t1.layer_id, coalesce(x.result, '[]'::jsonb) as result
  from table_1 t1
       left join expand x
              on x.layer_id = t1.layer_id
;

 layer_id |         result
----------+------------------------
        5 | {"a": 1, "c": "hello"}
        7 | []
(2 rows)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you!

I'm trying to figure out a way that the cross join could be avoided - it increases the execution time of the query three-fold. Do you think there is a way around it? If not, I am happy to accept your answer.

Comment: @Avocado  Sorry.  That should be a `cross join lateral`.  I have fixed it.  If that doesn't help, then it is likely the json processing that is slowing things down.

Comment: cool. Final question (I promise!) This is currently excluding rows that have an empty labels array. Is there a way to include those, and just return an empty object for the jsonb_object_agg?

Comment: @Avocado  Yes.  I have added an example of how to do that.

Comment: @Avocado If you have a better way to do it, then edit my answer to include it.  It is kind of difficult to read code in the comments.